# Make a recursive function exit if a condition is met?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to solve this problem in Python: "Write a function to return True when its argument is an array that has the same nesting structures and same corresponding length of nested arrays as the first array."

So I want to compare 2 lists, check if their elements are lists, and if so then check if the elements of these lists are lists, and so on, until I find the point where "original" doesn't match "other.

So far I've got:

```
def same_structure_as(original,other):

    print(type(original))
    print(type(other))

    # if either, but not both of original and other are a list, return False
    if (type(original) is list) != (type(other) is list):
        print("not match")
        return False

    print()


    if (type(original) is list):
        for i in range(len(original)):
            if (type(original[i]) is list): 
                same_structure_as(original[i],other[i])

    return True


print(same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ 2, 5 ] ))
```

However, the problem is that once I get to the "return False", it only returns False for this iteration. So the iterations above this will still return True, giving the below output when run:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>

<class 'list'>
<class 'int'>
not match
True
```

whereas I want the *entire* program to exit and return False immediately after "not match" gets printed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a check on the line of recursive calling function may help you to resolve your problem. By doing that when ever there is a mismatch it will return back False through all the steps of recursion.
def same_structure_as(original,other):

```
    print(type(original))
    print(type(other))

    # if either, but not both of original and other are a list, return False
    if (type(original) is list) != (type(other) is list):
        print("not match")
        return False

    print()


    if (type(original) is list):
        for i in range(len(original)):
            if (type(original[i]) is list):
                if(same_structure_as(original[i],other[i])==False):
                     return False

    return True


print(same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ 2, 5 ] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling `same_structure_as` for the elements of the list, but **you are not using the return value**.

The recursive part is called for each element of the list. You need to combine them together and return the combined result. The idea is that for two lists to return True, you need the following condition:

```
same_as(a[0], b[0]) && same_as(a[1], b[1]) && ... && same_as(a[n], b[n])
```

The logic of the function should be something like this:

```
def same_as(a ,b):

    # If the two elements have different types, then they're definitely not matching
    if type(a) != type(b):   return False
    
    # Now both elements are the same type. 
    
    # If they are not lists, it means there is no nested elements. So they have the same structure
    If type(a) is not list:  return True
    
    # At this point, both elements are lists. Check first if their sizes are the same
    if len(a) != len(b):    return False
    
    # Now the elements are lists of the same size. Compare each sub-element inside a loop
    # For the two lists to be the same structure, *ALL* their elements must be the same structure. 
    # We will use the AND operator 
    equal = False
    For i = 0:len(a):
       equal = equal && same_as(a[i], b[i])
    
    # Now the boolean 'equal' will be True ONLY if ALL the sub-elements returned True 
    return  equal
```